# I need help with math statistics for a game.

Tags: statistics

Ok so basically In the game that I play every user has a stats board right? It consists of wins, losses, kills, deaths. your WR (win rate) is also shown and KDR (kill death rate) is also shown. Since the game is small I thought of a fun project to do. Basically I would look at the stats of everyone with a 85 % wr or more AND has 200 wins at least. so for example someone can have 250 wins and 7 losses and would have around a 97 % win rate. Someone with 3000 wins and 400 losses would have and 88% WR. Heres what I want to do: I Want to make a top 10 list of the best statistics. heres the problem though, people with thousands of wins and a maintained 85 % wr have worked much hard than people with 200-500 wins with 85 % wr or more because as more games are added, the harder it is to maintain a good win rate. so someone with less wins might have a higher win rate, but I want to balance it out with the more wins the better, and of course higher win rate. I also want to factor in higher KDR like someone with 2000 kills and 1200 deaths having a 1.6 kdr which is pretty good. How can I factor in Win rate, KDR and high win count to make a balanced and accurate top 10 list IF possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a surprisingly simple solution to this, it's called **Laplace's Rule of Succession**. What you do is pretend each player played two extra "fake" games.  Of these, they won 1 and lost 1. Then, calculate their percentage based on these games as well.  The more games each player plays, the less their score will be affected by the fake games.

For example, your player with $250$ wins and $7$ losses, instead of calculating their win rate as $\frac{250}{257}\approx97.276\%$, pretend they actually had $251$ wins and $8$ losses.  This would give them a WR of $\frac{251}{259}\approx96.912\%$.
Your player with $3000$ wins and $400$ losses would have a WR of not $\frac{3000}{3400}\approx88.235\%$ but $\frac{3001}{3402}\approx88.213\%$.  (In fact, these numbers represent the probability that each of these players will win their *next* game, based only on the information provided.)

Notice that the first player lost $0.365\%$ to this method, while the second player lost only $0.022\%$.  This corresponds to the fact that the second player has played way more games than the first, and thus their score is more robust.

(3Blue1Brown has a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8idr1WZ1A7Q) on this, although it's a three-part series, of which he has only released the first two parts, and shown no signs of finishing it any time soon.)

Calculate this score for all your players, and the 10 highest are your champions.

Comment: That would make a win-loss record of $3000-400$ look slightly better than a record of $300-40$ but worse than a record of $301-40$. I am not sure that quite meets the expectation of the question

Comment: thanks thats very helpful @wolf elkah is there a way I can also factor in kill, death rate?

Comment: Combining multiple scores isn't as straightforward.  

There are two ways I can think of to include KDR.  You can either multiply them together, or take a weighted average of the two.  

The advantage of multiplication is that it's simpler, and you don't have to choose a somewhat arbitrary weight value.  

The potential disadvantage is that the higher your score in one area, the more your score in the other area matters.  This may or may not be a good metric, depending on the game.